# Vue Router nested paths break static assets path on manual refresh

Tags: webpack, vue-router

We're using VueJS 2.x with the *vue-cli* Webpack boilerplate, along with Vue Router. We've run into a problem where the following happens

- Our static assets sit in a root level *static* folder
- The assets paths are defined as follows in Webpack *config/index.js* file:

  ```
  assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
  assetsPublicPath: '/',
  ```
- Vue Router is running in *history* mode and we followed the official docs. for including the required Apache rewrite rule while running the router in history mode.

In our routes file there are some nested paths such as */dashboards/sampleDashboard*

When navigating to a nested path via the site navigation everything works fine. However, navigating manually (or doing a browser refresh) breaks the static assets path. The static assets path at this point includes the nested route path so something like *http://localhost:5001/static/bootstrap/boostrap.min.css* turns into *http://localhost:5001/dashboards/static/bootstrap/boostrap.min.css*

This does not happen for 1-level paths such as */reports* but only when we have a 2-level nested route.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. Any solution?

Comment: Not a permanent solution. I read somewhere that setting your base href to '/' fixes the issue and it did. However we are serving our site from "domainName/subfolder/" so our base href needs to be "/subfolder/". Doing that, causes the same issue all over again for 2-level nested paths. It gives the following error on manual/hard refresh:

`
    Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://trials-int.nci.nih.gov/strap/dashboards/static/layouts/theme/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css".

Comment: and on the compiled JS files the error is:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vendor.12e3e5d….js:1

Comment: You can see in the path to the theme CSS file that its attaching the relative path to the CSS file to the nested path instead of to the domain name/subfolder/. This only happens on the manual/hard refresh.

So far I've found no solutions but really need one.

Comment: I solved the same issue by removing a dot from my static assets: from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./build/main.min.css" type="text/css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/main.min.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156339/added-a-prop-with-vuerouter-and-a-css-file-stopped-loading-the-url-properly

Answer (score 0):

In webpack boilerplate templates for vue-cli 2.* versions, in webpack.base.conf.js file you have to change publicPath for fonts and images from

```
publicPath: '../../'
```

to

```
publicPath: '../../../'
```

the above one is for 3 levels, you can change to any number of levels based on url depth