# Relative path for iframe doesn't resolve in production

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my vuejs app I have an iframe which should show another app. However I always get an

> DOCUMENT NOT FOUND

In my component i wrote

```
<iframe src="/static/stbnotes/stbnotes.html"></iframe>
```

For my router I defined a *base* option

```
base: 'pat-os/'
```

This works fine in development - content will be loaded in the iframe. But not when creating a build using *npm run build* and load it from a server. The url for the iframe is now

```
http://localhost/static/stbnotes/stbnotes.html
```

where I want it to be

http://localhost/pat-os/static/stbnotes/stbnotes.html

How can I set a working relative path to the static folder (could be another folder as well) for the iframe?

Comment: If the current URL is `http://localhost/pat-os/something.html`, then you want `src="static/stbnotes/stbnotes.html`" (no leading slash)

Comment: @RoyJ The current URL might change depending on the current route. Usually the route where this iframe is displayed looks like: `localhost/pat-os/courseElement/6`. The example you gave doesn't work. In development `src="../../static/stbnotes(stbnotes.html` is fine. However in production it needs to be `src="../static/stbnotes(stbnotes.html` (one level less deep). Any other idea?

Comment: You can't use a relative path if you don't know what the current path is going to be. You can use a variable for the `src` attribute, maybe look up the value based on the possibilities for the current path.  I don't think I've quite clearly understood what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, the current path always consists of two levels, so the URL is changing, but the nesting should always be the same so a relative path should work. Finally all I want is to use a relative path to my static folder that work in both development and production. It doesn't seem to work - at least if I have a route with two levels. Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658791/vue-router-nested-paths-break-static-assets-path-on-manual-refresh